# Reviews are not working in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, review

I am using word press woocommerce plugin and I enabled all option for reviews on products.
But in the front end add review form is not showing. Any idea to enable product review for woocommerce.

Answer (score 15):

To make them visible, comments must be enabled in 'Quick Edit' menu on Products tab. “Bulk Edit” is a quick way to enable comments for all posts at once. Also check the "Allow others to post comments on new posts" options in options->discussion, it applies for future posts. WooCommerce option "Allow review only to "verified owners"" means that only logged in users that bought the product can leave comments.

Comment: This solved my problem. Apparently if you have reviews off, then create products, then turn them back on later, you need to follow these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure and check that you did not select that only logged in users or verified owners can add reviews.  If either are selected than it will not show up if you are not logged in or are not a verified owner.  Check and see if that is the issue then let me know.

Comment: I have unchecked that option.

Answer (score -1):

Randhir, I was having a similar issue to this. My Add Review button was showing but when I clicked on the button nothing happened. I didn't have any console errors and I couldn't figure it out for the longest time. I came across an article which described the problem and how to fix it. Please note that my Add To Cart button was also not working.

Basically my theme was not explicitly compatible with woocommerce and I didn't have a woocommerce loop file. Creating this file did the trick for me.

Here is the article http://chrislema.com/improving-the-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button/

Here is how I fixed it:

```
//Create a copy of page.php and name it woocommerce.php
//Replace the "has posts" loop
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h5><?php echo do_shortcode(get_the_title()); ?></h5>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

//With this code instead
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
```

Hope this helps.